# Debezium / kafka connect neither creating topics nor pushing data to created topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium-engine

I have zookeeper, kafka, and kafka connect running with a debezium plugin.
I cannot see any errors.
I have whitelisted a db and a couple of tables.
Upon inserts or updates to the tables no topic is created; and no data dir for the topics in /tmp/kafka-logs.
I just tried creating a topic for one of the tables (a kind of dummy table 't' with one column) but after inserting a row into t there is no data in the topic's log...a screenshot of the log follows

There is only one topic (the one I created, to see if it would be populated if I created it myself; I didn't expect it would be and it wasn't):

```
vagrant@coton:~$ ./kafka/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 1.2.3.4:9092 --list
vagrant.bet.t
vagrant@coton:~$
```

[image: some kafka connect log output]

The connector status is running:

```
vagrant@coton:~$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8083/connectors/pg-sport-connector/ | jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   940  100   940    0     0  50165      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 52222
{
  "name": "pg-sport-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "database.dbname": "sport",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "database.server.name": "vagrant",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "table.whitelist": "bet.event,bet.t",
    "internal.key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "decimal.handling.mode": "string",
    "database.hostname": "localhost",
    "database.password": "",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "internal.value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "name": "pg-sport-connector",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "database.whitelist": "sport",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "connector": "pg-sport-connector",
      "task": 0
    }
  ],
  "type": "source"
}

vagrant@coton:~$ curl -X GET http://localhost:8083/connectors/pg-sport-connector/status | jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   172  100   172    0     0  10876      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 11466
{
  "name": "pg-sport-connector",
  "connector": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "worker_id": "127.0.1.1:8083"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "state": "RUNNING",
      "worker_id": "127.0.1.1:8083"
    }
  ],
  "type": "source"
}
```

Running Java 8. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your config

```
"database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",  
"database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.your_topic_name"
```

Then check your topic name with this

```
./kafka/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list
```

After this, you can check for any changes in the tables

```
./kafka/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic your_topic_name
```

Comment: Thanks...tried it (added `"database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka3:9092",  
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.schema-changes-topic"`) but it didn't make any difference.  Topics are not created.  Inserts/deletes/updates do not result in any messages.

Comment: So running this `./kafka/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list` give you no results?

Comment: Plus, you write "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka**3**:9092". Make sure you write it correctly

Comment: I used kafka3 because that's the name of my docker container (I'm using zookeeper3, kafka3, debezium3).

Comment: Yes `./kafka/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list` gives only the topics created when I created the kafka container: `[kafka@d87cbbc449c8 ~]$ /kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh  --zookeeper zookeeper3:2181 --list
__consumer_offsets
my.connect.configs
my.connect.offsets
my.connect.statuses
`

Comment: The only directories in the data dir are for those topics.

Comment: To see the modify on a table, you need to run my last command. I honestly don't know if kafka write his changes of a topic into a log file but I don't think so.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean by "last command" but I've run all the commands.  Regarding kafka writing to log files, it writes all messages to to `log.dirs` location as defined in `<KAFKA_HOME>/config/server.properties`.

Comment: BTW I can't run the consumer command because there is no topic created that I can specify as an argument to the command.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout parameter "table.include.list". In my case problem was that I specified the value for this parameter as "test" (my table name), but it should be "public.test".